# How do I get the guys to appear in Minecraft PE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm posting on behalf of my 4.5 y/o son.  He has Minecraft PE on the iPad and sees all these YouTube videos of Minecraft with actual people there.  Do I have the wrong version?  Does it need to be on the computer?  Or does he have to be linked via WiFi to other players?  How do you get an actual player/guy/person?

Comment: Um... multiplayer?

Comment: It might be helpful if you linked one of the youtube videos to point out what you mean by "actual people".

Answer (score 6):

Minecraft pocket currently only supports Local WiFi.

You'll both need to have a device which has Minecraft pocket on it, and both be able to connect to the same WiFi network. On the main menu there are three options; Join Game, Start Game and Options.

Join game is the Local WiFi option. You'll both need to have set the 'server visible by default' option in the options menu.

[Actual multiplayer may be coming in future versions](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_Edition_upcoming_features) (currently it is version 0.6.1) but it isn't ready yet.

The videos you may be seeing could be from the Desktop version, or possibly the Xbox version. Both are different versions of minecraft with separate features and options compared to pocket edition.

Answer (score 2):

The current version 0.7.4 alpha allows you to connect to a server. The option is really hidden:

1. Select the button PLAY
2. Click Edit
3. The button beside the edit button will now be labeled "EXTERNAL"
4. Click it and select your server IP/name and port.

Now you can play in a server.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the videos about Minecraft you saw your son watching from YouTube is actually in the PC Version, not the PE Version. Thought that the PE Version supported multiplayer now.

Answer (score -1):

I think your son is expecting to see his own guy?

- In the app, go to setting, look for the setting marked "third-person", toggle it to the other position.

Comment: If you want to clarify something, earn some reputation and post a comment asking for more information. Then post an answer with the information you got. (If you still need to)