# Hosting my own server for Minecraft pocket edition

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

With my Minecraft Pocket edition version 0.7.4 I can [connect to an external server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/132267/56041), but I'm not able to connect to a server I'm running in my computer.

I've post [detailed information](http://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1992982-help-me-to-configure-a-local-linux-server/&ei=yIJEUr7AIobE9gS9uYCAAQ&usg=AFQjCNGU9jZl3VskHwUdfUuHjcOGxJym1g&sig2=eZ1CClQUZ6bb_UAGO5S9WQ&bvm=bv.53217764,d.eWU) about my setup in another forum. Am I doing something wrong? Do I need a special server to connect the pocket edition version?

Comment: Minecraft pocket is on a different spectrum than the normal servers from my understanding. I dont mean bluetooth I mean that the data files are not the same. Just as you can't join an xbox 360 server, the mobile cannot join PC and vice-versa.

Comment: @shanodin The usual tagging practices apply here: Minecraft PE is not Minecraft (PC) so it doesn't get the [minecraft] tag.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - ah my 'pologies - I was only half paying attention, it's been a long week

Comment: @shanodin S'cool, cool. It's almost Friday. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't host a server for Minecraft Pocket Edition using the PC dedicated Minecraft server. Despite the name and visual similarity, in software terms Minecraft and Minecraft PE are completely unrelated and incompatible games.

There are currently two options for hosting a PE server:

- Running an Android simulator on a PC and running Minecraft PE on that.
- Using [PocketMine-MP](http://www.pocketmine.net/) server software.

Comment: Is PocketMine-MP stable? My children are stumbling with a lot of bugs.

Comment: @neves I'm sorry, I really don't know. I don't host a PE server myself; I just know these are the only two options for doing so.

Comment: @neves It's marked as an alpha release.  That basically means, no, it's not stable yet.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple, easy, bug-free, full feature MineCraft PE server, the easiest way is to just use a dedicated iPod, iPad, or iPhone.
Unfortunately, there is not currently a way to convert worlds from your MCPC to your MCPE server.

Simply: - Used an old iPod Touch, iPad, iPhone,

- Install the app (free since you already bought it),
- Set lock screen time to "never" (Settings > General > Auto-Lock > Never),
- Start the app
- Set volume to zero
- Place on shelf on a charger
- Forget about it, it just simply works, all the time.

You can copy an existing world from your current device with free programs like iExplorer. Copy your world to the "server idevice", now everyone in the house can join from their device.

Comment: Good answer, but it is also necessary to open the router ports.