# Can I use Minecraft PC textures and worlds in Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Now that I've discovered that I can host a [Minecraft Pocket Edition server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132270/hosting-my-own-server-for-minecraft-pocket-edition), I'd like to know if is it possible to use the textures and maps of the PC version for the pocket version.

I'm planning to visit Peru and Machu Picchu. It would be really cool to entice them for the voyage by letting them play a [Machu Picchu world](http://www.planetminecraft.com/project/advparepic-god-of-deceit-3-hour-adventure/) in their favourite video game. Unfortunately, this God of Deceit world looks really sophisticated. I don't believe the Pocket Edition would be able to play it.

Answer (score 1):

For the textures, you can easily change it by changing the terrain.png file with your desired texture pack. But beware that PC's terrain.png may vary with PE's. Try searching for a similar or exact texture on the Minecraft Forums. They have lots of ported texture pack.

For maps, you will need to first port it because MCPE maps aren't infinite and a portion of the world will need to be cut, pasted and then saved in MCPE format. Then you can transfer it to your Android device.

Note: My previous answer was for iOS devices. I have changed my answer to fit the question and hope it helps.

Comment: How would one go about convering a PC world to a PE world, exactly?

Comment: Worlds are infinite if you have a phone that can run it. (5th Gen upwards)