# Do PC texture packs work on mcpe and vice versa?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've been looking for mcpe stuff and I saw that there was separate forums and tags for mcpe texture packs and for PC texture packs.

There are a couple of texture packs that I adore that are on PC and I was wondering if I could download them onto my tablet and that they would work on mcpe. Also if I could download mcpe texture packs and they would be able to work on PC.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use Minecraft PC textures and worlds in Pocket Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132297/can-i-use-minecraft-pc-textures-and-worlds-in-pocket-edition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I can only assume they wouldn't.**

The PC edition of Minecraft has a lot more features than the Pocket Edition has. Due to this, there will be a chance that the textures for each block will be in a different place than is required for the Pocket Edition. It's safe to say that they are definitely not aimed for Pocket Edition, *only PC*.

Comment: What about mcpe to PC?

Comment: You couldn't be even more out of luck there. *MISSING TEXTURES OUT THE BUTT!*

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, pc and pe are different platforms, and therefore cannot use the same packs. However, some sites give you different skins and skin packs that will work on them.