# How can I transfer a Minecraft Java Edition save to Minecraft Windows 10 (Bedrock) Edition save?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a Minecraft Java Edition file that I would like to convert to use in Minecraft Bedrock Edition on Windows 10.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Hi DarkAssassinBoy, welcome to Arqade! I'm not sure I understand your question. What version of Minecraft and what OS are you transferring from, and what version of Minecraft and OS are you transferring to? Lastly, what conversion tools have you already tried? There are multiple tools online that let you convert worlds, we just need to know which one you're after.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use Minecraft PC textures and worlds in Pocket Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132297/can-i-use-minecraft-pc-textures-and-worlds-in-pocket-edition)