# Can you host a minecraft pe server for free without having to be on the same wifi?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to play multiplayer Minecraft Pocket Edition with my friend, but he lives in a different state. Is there any way we can play together for free without being on the same wifi?

Comment: users, please comment when you down vote to create constructive criticism.

Comment: @ylun there is no requirement to comment when downvoting

Comment: then there will be no way for new users to learn.

Comment: @ylun The downvotes were probably given before Shanodin fixed the post. Presumably due to the lack of detail and horrific abuse of capital letters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hosting my own server for Minecraft pocket edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132270/hosting-my-own-server-for-minecraft-pocket-edition)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible:

Solution 1:

- Use PocketMine to host a server on your PC.
- Forward the port of your **PC** so it's accessible from the outside.
- Tell your friend your **external** IP so he can connect to the PocketMine server.

**Solution 2** (probably the one you're interested in):

- Find out the IP of your smartphone/tablet.
- Create a port forwarding for that IP on your router.
- Tell your friend your **external** IP, so he can connect.

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can. There are several apps that let you do something like this or at least join an existing server. Try to google something like "Minecraft PE Multiplayer Server App" and have fun ;)